# Compare array of images to another array of images to find duplicate images

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, duplicates, nsarray, nsset

i am finding Duplicate image using this code.

```
for (int i=0; i<arrImageData1.count; i++)
    {
        for (int j=i+1; j<arrImageData1.count; j++)
        {
            if ([arrImageData1[i]isEqualToData:arrImageData2[j]])
            {
                NSNumber *iValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
                NSNumber *jValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:j];
                [arr addObject:iValue];
                [arr addObject:jValue];
            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",arr);
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)arr.count);
    for (int k=0; k<arr.count; k++)
    {
        [arrDuplicateImages addObject:[arrImage objectAtIndex:[[arr objectAtIndex:k] integerValue]]];
        [arrAsset addObject:[self.assetsFetchResults objectAtIndex:[[arr objectAtIndex:k] integerValue]]];
    }
```

when i run on simulator it works perfectly but when i run it in device it gives me lots of duplicate images.number of images in device is 1206 and it gives me duplicate images 84448. any solution for this?

Comment: or suggest me anyother method to find duplicate images from array.

Comment: can you show us the complete code..? maybe you are mixing up some arrays

Comment: Why record both `i` and `j` as dupes?  Why not just `i` *or* `j`?

Comment: @trojanfoe beacuse i want to display both duplicate image.thats why i take i and j both

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava above is the complete logic to find duplicate